# Bottle and Python. Change format of a static_file while downloading

Tags: python, html, bottle

Good afternoon. I am trying to download a file with bottle. But it always downloads it with a .html format. How can i change it to a .txt? Thank you very much. My code is the following:

```
@get('/api/v1/descargarHist/<id>')
def descargar (id):
directorio, fichero = Repo.recuperar_historial(id)
return static_file(fichero, root=directorio,download='{}.txt'.format(id))
```

No matter how much i try, i can't change it. It always downloads it as a .html Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`static_file` [takes a `mimetype` parameter](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#static-files):

```
return static_file(fichero, root=directorio, download='{}.txt'.format(id), mimetype='text/plain')
```